# Why does this regex misfire on css?

Tags: regex, apache

I'd like any files not matching my extension list to be forced to download and so I added

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)(?<!\.css|\.eot|\.flv|\.gif|\.html|\.ico|\.jpeg|\.jpg|\.js|\.json|\.m4v|\.mov|\.mp3|\.ogg|\.pdf|\.png|\.svg|\.ttf|\.txt|\.webm|\.webp|\.woff|\.xhtml|\.xml)$">
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

to `.htaccess` but I am getting the header on CSS files as well. Running https://regex101.com/r/M26y55/4 says "Your regular expression does not match the subject string."

Comment: What is your expected match? Right now you are asserting the end of the string if what precedes is not any of the listed so it does not match, as `foo/x.css` ends with .css

Comment: I want any file not listed to be forced to download. Edited.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/gzePnY/1

Comment: Exactly. x.custom should download x.css should not.

Comment: Perhaps you could match till the last `/`, then till the last `.` Assert what is on the right is not any of the listed extension and if it is not, match any char except a whitespace char or a `.` till the end of the string. https://regex101.com/r/6ouyKO/1